# Why do we need to give url while sending post request via XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

const xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST',url,true);

Let params="name"="Rahul"
xhr.send(params)

Cannot understand why we use url in post request

Comment: How else is it supposed to know where to send the request?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is not like a form that has a page's state to know where to post the form to if the action is not set. You need to set the location so it knows where to send it to. If you want the current page, then use `window.location.href`.